# Adding new server to PhpPgAdmin

Tags: php, postgresql, phppgadmin

I want to write web app with PostgreSQL database that I already have. So is it even possible to add another server to PhppgAdmin? If it is how should I do it?

Comment: PhpPgAdmin has a conf file  that explains it quite good https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/blob/master/conf/config.inc.php-dist

Comment: Are you talking about another server (on a different machine) or another database? Those are two different things

Comment: @M.Eriksson I need another server where I have completed database. So I think I need to import whole server.

Comment: @nbk thank you it helped me a little bit. But now I have problem with this error: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not translate host name "" to address: Unknown server error in C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\drivers\adodb-postgres64.inc.php on line 765

Comment: without seeing teh conf not, but follow the documenattiom and start from scratch